# iphone: NSMutable array is empty when using addObject in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I am parsing data using NSXMLParser.
I am able to get the parsed data. But when I add it to the NSMutableArray using addObject, the array is empty.
I am using the latest Xcode version.
Can someone please help me out.

The array I am working on is identificationTypes1

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {

        self.identificationTypes1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        }

    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    if (!currentElementValue) {
        currentElementValue =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];

    }
    else {
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    }


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        NSLog(@"Count is %@",[identificationTypes1 count]);

        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {

    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        NSLog(@"Curre value is %@",currentElementValue);
        [self.identificationTypes1 addObject:currentElementValue];


    }

   currentElementValue = nil;

}
```

Comment: Odds are about 70% that you never created the mutable array.

Comment: yep, must be Xcode's fault...

Comment: give the complete code and also NSLog the parsed data to see wether data is coming or not

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutabeArray *myArray = [[NSMUtableArray alloc]init];

[myArray addObject:<XML Data>];
```

Comment: There is no `addObjects:`, only `-arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` or `-addObject:`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest elements as you have in didStartElement. Parsers do not allow that.
Take out the title out on its own and retest. You need to make new variables that are accessed conditionally.